# let over lambda doesn't seem to work in elisp

Tags: emacs, lexical-scope, let-over-lambda

In Common Lisp this sort of thing works fine

```
(let ((x 7))
  (defun g (y) (* y x)))

(g 16)
```

In elisp this errors saying x is not defined as if the lexical closure did not happen.  This is something I have not encountered in other lisps.  What is happening with this?

Comment: This might be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I see.  It works after

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
```